# How is Istio's service discovery different from K8s' default service discovery?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

In Kubernetes, you can implement service discovery by default using the Service resource. For example, a Pod named A can call a service named B by making a request to `{SERVICE}.svc.cluster.local`.
But if you look at Istio's documentation, it says that Istio provides Service discovery. How is service discovery with Istio different from the service discovery provided by K8s by default?